# Dynamic document lookup

Tags: xslt-2.0

I’m trying to come up with a way to dynamically determine which XML document to use for lookups. I parse the input XML document and based on the value I would like to set the appropriate lookup document to use. Ideally I would to have $ LookupDoc set to the correct document to read. The code snippet I have below doesn’t work. I could switch to XSLT 3.0 if that makes it easier.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:key name="table-lookup" match="Row" use="@Key1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="LookupLTE" select="document('HuaweiLTE.xml')/Huawei"/>
    <xsl:variable name="LookupHSPA" select="document('HuaweiHSPA.xml')/Huawei"/>
    <xsl:template match="measCollecFile/measData">
        <xsl:variable name="DeviceName" select="@userLabel"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="substring($DeviceName,1,1)='L'">
                <xsl:variable name="LookupDoc" select="$LookupLTE"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="substring($DeviceName,1,1)='H'">
                <xsl:variable name="LookupDoc" select="$LookupHSPA"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="measInfo">
                <xsl:call-template name="loop"> </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not shown any use of the variable named `LookupDoc` you seem to want to define but I think you can simply use `<xsl:variable name="LookupDoc" select="if (substring($DeviceName,1,1)='L') then $LookupLTE else if (substring($DeviceName,1,1)='H') then $LookupHSPA else ()"/>` to define the variable.

Comment: Sorry I guess that would help. <xsl:value-of select="key('table-lookup', $curr_key, $LookupDoc)/@ColumnName"/>

Comment: Try what I have suggested (in place of the `xsl:chooose` you currently have), if it does not work then you need to edit your question and show us where/how you use `<xsl:value-of select="key('table-lookup', $curr_key, $LookupDoc)/@ColumnName"/>` as it is not clear whether that happens in the template `match="measCollecFile/measData"` or in a different template.

Comment: The if example you provided worked like a charm, thank you.